# What is the structure of the Android source repository at Google Git?

Tags: android, architecture, structure, open-source, android-source

I am familiar with this android architecture model:[image]

But when I browse android repository at google git I just can't figure out exactly what files should exist in which folder. What exactly is the folder structure of the android git? Also another question, Is there any specific reason why 'Core Libraries' shown in picture inside 'ANDROID RUNTIME' block sits below 'APPLICATION FRAMEWORK' block? Keeping in mind how apps interact with 'Core Libraries' they should sit beside 'APPLICATION FRAMEWORK' block not below it.

Comment: You should add android-source tag. It is a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think here is the starting point to dig out the AOSP

**abi**: Minimal C++ Run-Time Type Information support

**bionic**: Android’s custom C library

**bootable**: OTA, recovery mechanism and reference bootloader

**build**: Build system

**cts**: Comptability Test Suite

**dalvik**: Dalvik VM

**development**: Development tools

**device**: Device-specific files and components

**docs**: Content of http://source.android.com

**external**: External projects imported into the AOSP

**frameworks**: Core components such as system services

**hardware**: HAL and hardware support libraries

**libcore**: Apache Harmony

**libnativehelper**: Helper functions for use with JNI

**ndk**: Native Development Kit

**packages**: Stock Android apps, providers

**pdk**: Platform Development Kit

**prebuilt**: Prebuilt binaries, including toolchains

**prebuilts**: Replacement for prebuilt

**sdk**: Software Development Kit

**system**: “Embedded Linux” platform that houses Android

**tools**: Various IDE tools

[image]

I hope it will be helpful for you 
[reference](http://www.staroceans.org/kernel-and-driver/%5BEmbedded.Android(2013.3)%5D.Karim.Yaghmour.pdf)